# how to implement the effect in android as described below

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

My android application has four activities, I want theme to be in accordance with four icon in tabs or in action bar, or something like that. When a indicator for its activity is pressed, the corresponding activity will be launched, and when an activity is launched its indicator is highlighted. I tried using tabsActivity in android. The only lack is if an activity is launched not by pressing its tab, the tabs will not show and its corresponding tab of course will not be highlighted. Would somebody give me some clue or instructions to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you have a custom View which implements the tab bar and add it to each of the Activities, and in each, handle the button clicks to bring up the appropriate Activity.